# MS SQL does not return the expected top row when ordering by DIFFERENCE()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have noticed strange behaviour in some SQL code used for address matching at the company I work for & have created some test SQL to illustrate the issue.

```
; WITH Temp (Id, Diff) AS (

    SELECT 9218, 0
    UNION
    SELECT 9219, 0
    UNION
    SELECT 9220, 0

)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Temp ORDER BY Diff DESC
```

Returns **9218** but

```
; WITH Temp (Id, Name) AS (

    SELECT 9218, 'Sonnedal'
    UNION
    SELECT 9219, 'Lammermoor'
    UNION
    SELECT 9220, 'Honeydew'

)

SELECT TOP 1 *, DIFFERENCE(Name, '')  FROM Temp ORDER BY DIFFERENCE(Name, '') DESC
```

returns **9219** even though the Difference() is 0 for all records as you can see here:

```
; WITH Temp (Id, Name) AS (

    SELECT 9218, 'Sonnedal'
    UNION
    SELECT 9219, 'Lammermoor'
    UNION
    SELECT 9220, 'Honeydew'

)

SELECT  *, DIFFERENCE(Name, '')  FROM Temp ORDER BY DIFFERENCE(Name, '') DESC
```

which returns

```
9218    Sonnedal    0
9219    Lammermoor  0
9220    Honeydew    0
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I am writing C# to replace existing SQL & need to return the same results so I can test that my code produces the same results. But I can't see why the actual SQL used returns 9219 rather than 9218 & it doesn't seem to make sense. It seems it's down to the Difference() function but it returns 0 for all the record in question.

Comment: you get random row

Answer (score 3):

When you call:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, DIFFERENCE(Name, '')
FROM Temp l
ORDER BY DIFFERENCE(Name, '') DESC
```

All three records have a `DIFFERENCE` value of zero, and hence SQL Server is free to choose from *any* of the three records for ordering.  That is to say, there is no guarantee which order you will get.  The same is true for your second query.  Actually, it is possible that the ordering for the same query could even change over time.  In practice, if you expect a certain ordering, you should provide exact logic for it, e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Temp
ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: You say it's random but it's always in the same row. Even if there are 1000s of rows, SQL always returns the 2nd row, even on different days. If it is truly random then surely different results will be returned? It's not my SQL otherwise I would have put in more ordering criteria :)

Comment: It may appear stable, but if you did something like rebuild the index, add/delete data, it could change.  And the key point here is that SQL Server will give you no guarantees about what you will get back.  Just add `ORDER BY` and forget about it.